# How to make an `Option` to be None by inner field in serde?

Tags: rust, serde

```rust
use serde_derive::Deserialize; // 1.0.118
use toml; // 0.5.8

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Remote {
    enabled: bool,
    address: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    remote: Option<Remote>,
}


fn main() {
    let config: Config = toml::from_str(r#"
    [remote]
    enabled = true
    address = "example.com"
    "#).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", config);

    let config: Config = toml::from_str(r#"
    [remote]
    enabled = false
    address = "example.com"
    "#).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", config);
    // How to make `config.remote` `None` ?
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9fa5e5c620cb38498fc13a9fddada578)

I want the rest fields of `Remote` to be optional and `Config::remote` to be `None` when `enabled` is set to false.

I tried `tag` attribute but didn't work as expected.

Comment: Why not just check if `enabled` is set to `false` post-deserialization and if it is just convert `config.remote` from `Some` to `None`?

Comment: You could also manually implement `Deserialize`, but this is incredibly painful and probably not worth it.

Comment: @Aplet123 Check out my answer. Serde makes it relatively easy to override on a case-by-case basis, but there's definitely some pain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Believe it or not, you actually can do this using the `#[serde(deserialize_with = "...")]` attribute. It lets you override the deserializer applied to a certain field. The goal here is to use an overriding deserializer that calls the regular deserializer, then checks the enabled field manually. This is (thinly) documented on the [serde website](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with).

First, the code:

```rust
// Important: Deserialize is needed to access T::deserialize() methods.
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};

fn none_if_disabled<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Option<Remote>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let remote = Option::<Remote>::deserialize(deserializer)?;

    Ok(remote.and_then(|r| if r.enabled { Some(r) } else { None }))
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Remote {
    enabled: bool,
    address: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "none_if_disabled")]
    remote: Option<Remote>,
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=581e27e6c4e43a75ac934cda1c47b289)

Lets break it down. The function signature is a little gnarly if you're not familiar with serde's internals.

```rust
fn none_if_disabled<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Option<Remote>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
```

`D` is something that implements `Deserializer`. This is generally provided by the parser crate, in this case [toml](https://docs.rs/toml/0.5.8/toml/de/struct.Deserializer.html), though [other parsers](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/struct.Deserializer.html) have their own. We can ask `D` to try and give us various primitives, or we can pass it into something that implements `Deserialize`, which will consume these primitives for us. We need to return either the successful parsed value (`Option<Remote>`) or bubble up any errors that we get.

Inside the function, the first step is to use the regular `Deserialize` impl that we got from `#[derive(Deserialize)]` on `Remote`. This is the "normal" parsing step, and is roughly what would be called if we didn't have a `deserialize_with` attribute.

```rust
let remote = Option::<Remote>::deserialize(deserializer)?;
```

Then, we need the filtering logic. This can be as complex as you need it to be, as long as it outputs a `Result<Option<Remote>, _>`.

```rust
Ok(remote.and_then(|r| if r.enabled { Some(r) } else { None }))
```

Finally, we need to tell serde about our fancy deserializer.

```rust
#[serde(deserialize_with = "none_if_disabled")]
```

The output with your `main` function is:

```rust
Config { remote: Some(Remote { enabled: true, address: "example.com" }) }
Config { remote: None }
```

This works, but only with a bunch of additional complexity. @Skarlett is completely correct that serde isn't really built for this kind of configuration management, and you might be better off with a post-processing pass on the stuff serde parses for you directly. My preferred approach would be to keep all of your `Remote`s in place and explicitly change behavior based on the `enabled` flag -- this allows you to do things with the disabled configurations, such as explicitly logging that a connection was not attempted.

That said, these uses of serde do have a place, even if a configuration file probably isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Like @pretzelhammer said, this is probably the most fair approach. This is something you cannot express easily to serde. Serde is primarily for just serialization, not management of the data. You as the programmer are responsible for inferring the logic behind the rules.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2a79969788b9f07e15b1430efc512861